# Server.MapPath returning incorrect path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have an MVC app and deployed to a Server, which i have only ftp access, the name of the app is `test.foo.com`. There is a backend which users upload pictures to the app. Everything works great. The code is as follow:

```
//in web config this is the value
<add key="NewsImagesPath" value="~/App_Data/NewsImages/" />

// this is in controller
private static readonly string news_images_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsImagesPath"]; 

// in the method
String uploadedFile = fileUploadHelper.UploadFile(file, Server.MapPath(news_images_path));
```

and here the fileuploadhelper which returns the uploaded path:

```
public class FileUploadHelper
{
    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
    { 
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        { 
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + fileInfo.Extension;
            var uploadPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            file.SaveAs(uploadPath);
            return uploadPath;
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

Well this code works fine.

The problem is when this app was deployed to `foo.com` . Pictures are still being uploaded to `test.foo.com` App_Data folder.

ie: I am uploading an image from foo.com and image is being stored under :

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.foo.com\App_Data
```

whereas it should go to

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo.com\App_Data
```

Why is this happening?

I dont know how the server, IIS was configured.

Comment: You'll need to find out how IIS was configured. The hostname bindings don't affect where the application root directory is in the filesystem.

Comment: what are the things i need to look within IIS configuration?

Comment: The application home directory is what matters. You can't view that over FTP though, so ask your hoster.

Comment: Well i find it out, when i delete the test.foo.com app folder. images disappered from foo.com but app is still running. so the bin, views etc is there but the images are being uploaded to `test.foo.com`. so it is related to Server.MapPath.

Comment: are both test.foo.com and foo.com in the same application pool?

Comment: @NickBray might be, not sure, i m not managing the server. do u think that s the problem?

Comment: I think Server.MapPath("~") gets the application root directory.  Both sites can be considered by IIS to be the same application based on how they are configured. You can try Serer.MapPath(".") to get the current directory of the executing code.

Comment: If i remove the `test.foo.com` from app pool, which i m not sure if both are in the same pool, would that work?

Comment: Remove the ~ from your key.

Comment: @Pete i doubt `~` is causing the problem.

Comment: @Pete try removing at prod? :) i dont think so. but why would u think removing that would help?

Comment: Server.MapPath("/") will map to the root of your domain (which isn't necessarily the root of the application, but in your case it is, based on what you posted above).

Comment: But I m using Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") not Server.MapPath("/").

Comment: @NickBray  i just checked they are not in the same app pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Server.MapPath("~")` is pointing to the physical root folder of where the ASP.NET application is configured to run under. So I guess there's some configuration in IIS so that both `test.foo.com` and `foo.com` are actually pointing to the same application. If you do not have access to the server to check this out, there's not much you could do other than contacting your hosting provider and ask for more details about how those domains are setup and which applications they are mapped to.

Comment: Thanks. I will contact hosting provider.